# C embedded change values of struct from another file

Tags: c, arduino, embedded, arduino-uno

Hello I am working on a small roboter project at uni and I have run into following issue.
I have a typedef called RoboterData inside of a header file because I want to make use of it across multiple files. Inside of the main file I have a RoboterData data variable which holds important data.

My goal is to have access from other files to this data having the ability to get and set it from another file. I want to avoid the use of a global variable.

Here are the relevant code fragments of my approach:

**main.h**

```
typedef struct {
    DriveMode mode;
    short sensor_left;
    short sensor_mid;
    short sensor_right;
    int left_eng_speed;
    int right_eng_speed;
} RoboterData;
```

**main.c**

```
# include "motors.h"

// The Data I want to get and set from other files.
RoboterData data;

// Call to a funcion defined in motors.c
drive_straight(RoboterData *data);
```

**motors.h**

```
void drive_straight(RoboterData *data);
```

**motors.c**

```
# include "main.h"

enum {
    ENG_STILL = 0,
    ENG_SLOW = 50,
    ENG_MID = 155,
    ENG_FAST = 200
}

void drive_straight(RoboterData *data) {
    data ->left_eng_speed = ENG_FAST;
    data ->right_eng_speed = ENG_FAST;
    set_duty_cycle(LEFT_ENG, ENG_FAST);
    set_duty_cycle(RIGHT_ENG, ENG_FAST);
}
```

When I later try to print out the values left_eng_speed and right_eng_speed via serial port it stays at 0. I know C is call by value but since I am passing a ptr to my struct the value I am passing is the adress of the struct and when I dereference it via '->' I should be able to access its original data from my understanding and not a copy because the only thing I copied was the address.

If someone could explain to me why this is not working and provide a viable alternative, I would be very greatfull.

Comment: Do you have `void drive_straight(RoboterData *data);` in `main.c` or a file included by it? (Should be in `motors.h`, and included by `main.c`.) Make sure to enable your compiler's warnings!!!

Comment: Re "*the only thing I copied was the address.*", Correct, the function modifies the caller's structure.

Comment: I think from what I posted it is clear I have it inside of motors.c. But you are right I did not show the header file in main.c. I update that

Comment: IMO, the very existence of a `main.h` file is a sign of bad hierarchical design.

Comment: Re "*I think from what I posted it is clear I have it inside of motors.c.*", I didn't ask about `void drive_straight(RoboterData *data) { ... }`. Read what I wrote again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Call to a funcion defined in motors.c
drive_straight(RoboterData *data);
```

This is a function declaration. It doesn't *do* anything. You want

```
drive_straight(&data);
```

to actually call the function.

Comment: You are right. I feel dumb now. Thanks a lot dumb mistake ...

Comment: oof! Re "*Thanks a lot dumb mistake*", No, that was not enabling your compiler's warnings. I'm surprised that even compiles without are return type. But putting that in a function would surely warn! So, ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings.

Comment: @ikegami: It compiles just fine. The default return type if omitted is still `int`. It's like writing `extern variable;` And the declaration masks the global declaration so there's no type conflict. Yes I wish that warned too (haven't checked) because you're masking a type of an external symbol with a different type of the same external symbol.